# tailwind style not applying in next js when using official cli to generate project

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am following the [tailwind doc](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs) to generate nextJs app.

```
npx create-next-app -e with-tailwindcss .
```

Then I've created `NavBar` component by copying the code of [tailwind doc](https://v1.tailwindcss.com/components/navigation#responsive-header)

NavBar.js

```
import React from "react";

function NavBar() {
  return (
    <nav className="flex items-center justify-between flex-wrap bg-teal-500 p-6">
      <div className="flex items-center flex-shrink-0 text-white mr-6">
        <svg
          className="fill-current h-8 w-8 mr-2"
          width="54"
          height="54"
          viewBox="0 0 54 54"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
          <path d="M13.5 22.1c1.8-7.2 6.3-10.8 13.5-10.8 10.8 0 12.15 8.1 17.55 9.45 3.6.9 6.75-.45 9.45-4.05-1.8 7.2-6.3 10.8-13.5 10.8-10.8 0-12.15-8.1-17.55-9.45-3.6-.9-6.75.45-9.45 4.05zM0 38.3c1.8-7.2 6.3-10.8 13.5-10.8 10.8 0 12.15 8.1 17.55 9.45 3.6.9 6.75-.45 9.45-4.05-1.8 7.2-6.3 10.8-13.5 10.8-10.8 0-12.15-8.1-17.55-9.45-3.6-.9-6.75.45-9.45 4.05z" />
        </svg>
        <span className="font-semibold text-xl tracking-tight">Tailwind CSS</span>
      </div>
      <div className="block lg:hidden">
        <button className="flex items-center px-3 py-2 border rounded text-teal-200 border-teal-400 hover:text-white hover:border-white">
          <svg
            className="fill-current h-3 w-3"
            viewBox="0 0 20 20"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          >
            <title>Menu</title>
            <path d="M0 3h20v2H0V3zm0 6h20v2H0V9zm0 6h20v2H0v-2z" />
          </svg>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="w-full block flex-grow lg:flex lg:items-center lg:w-auto">
        <div className="text-sm lg:flex-grow">
          <a
            href="#responsive-header"
            className="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0 text-teal-200 hover:text-white mr-4"
          >
            Docs
          </a>
          <a
            href="#responsive-header"
            className="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0 text-teal-200 hover:text-white mr-4"
          >
            Examples
          </a>
          <a
            href="#responsive-header"
            className="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0 text-teal-200 hover:text-white"
          >
            Blog
          </a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a
            href="#"
            className="inline-block text-sm px-4 py-2 leading-none border rounded text-white border-white hover:border-transparent hover:text-teal-500 hover:bg-white mt-4 lg:mt-0"
          >
            Download
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}

export default NavBar;
```

The appearance of NavBar is not same as the doc
[image]

This is what the `NavBar` should look like:
[image]

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  purge: ['./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}', './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

postcss.config.js

```
// If you want to use other PostCSS plugins, see the following:
// https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

_app.js

```
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import "tailwindcss/tailwind.css";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Layout.js

```
import React from 'react';
import NavBar from '../components/NavBar';

function Layout({children}) {
    return (
        <>
        <NavBar/>
        <div>
            <main>
                {children}
            </main>
        </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Layout
```

Comment: If that's from some official code and you didn't do anything else than following the doc, I think it's ok to open a ticket on the relevant GitHub repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the `teal` not being associated with a color so adding `theme: { colors: require('tailwindcss/colors') }` to `tailwind.config.js` fixes it.

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    colors: require('tailwindcss/colors'),
  },
}
```